# ASP.Net Core works in IIS only without site host name

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-core, iis-10

I just deployed my ASP.core Angular4 app to IIS.
Everything works fine if I run the site without a host name. 
With a given hostname the site is not reachable.

Any ideas whats wrong? I guess it's something simple but couldn't solve it so far.

Comment: If not use the Angular Template of Visual Studio 2017, try remove <base href='./'> of your index.html. If you are using angular-cli, check the --base-href from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: may need to update hosts file with hostname